# DB2 - C embedded SQL won't insert a row

Tags: c, ubuntu, db2, sql-insert

I am trying to build a C program to generate partly random strings and insert a large number of them to db2 rows in a loop so I need it to insert from embedded SQL.... The program does everything except inserts.

I can make a select query, c compiler, db2 precompiler and binder all execute with no errors.
It does not even let me make an insert with hard coded variables let alone with host variables and the query is perfectly successful from terminal line

```
db2 "INSERT INTO
 SYT006_COUNTRY(SL_ISO2,BZ_COUNTRY,KZ_RISK)
 VALUES
 ('XY', 'wont work from embedded SQL', 'R')"
```

Host variables defined as char arrays with one more position for terminator. Platform is Ubuntu.

I tried a million things so here is the code.. EDIT everything obsolete cleared

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sqlca.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <sqlenv.h>
    #include <sqlcodes.h>
    #include <sqlutil.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include "utilemb.h"
    #include "sqlaprep.h"

    /* SQL includes */
      EXEC SQL INCLUDE SQLCA;
      EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;

      EXEC SQL DECLARE     SYT006_COUNTRY TABLE
                (
                  KEYFIELD                            INT,
                  SL_ISO2                             CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
                  BZ_COUNTRY                          CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                  KZ_RISK                             CHAR(1) NOT NULL
                ) ;


        char       hostVar[31];

      EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

    int main()
    {
      /* connect to the database REQUIRED */
    printf("Connecting to database...\n ");
    EXEC SQL CONNECT TO "sample";
    if (SQLCODE  <0)
    {
       printf("Connect Error. Code: %d\n",  sqlca.sqlcode);
    }
    else
    {
       printf("Connected to database. Code: %d\n",sqlca.sqlcode );
    }

    /* works only from command line terminal*/
      EXEC SQL
      INSERT INTO
      SYT006_COUNTRY(SL_ISO2,BZ_COUNTRY,KZ_RISK)
      VALUES
      ('XY', 'please', 'R');


    /* this one works perfectly normal*/
    /*
        EXEC SQL SELECT BZ_COUNTRY INTO :hostVar
        FROM SYT006_COUNTRY WHERE   KEYFIELD = 515;
        printf("printing hostVar: %s\n", hostVar);
    */
        printf("MAIN FINISH \n");
    return (0);
    }/*end main*/
```

the only out of order thing I get is when i start db2 from my shell script:

SQL5043N  Support for one or more communications protocols specified in the DB2COMM environment variable failed to start successfully. However, core database manager functionality started successfully.
SQL1063N  DB2START processing was successful.

Comment: No COBOL yet. This is all SQC, and not the precompiled C. At the end of the code there are two queries. Select does the job all the time, insert does not. Everything compiles, sqlca.sqlcode returns zero but the row is not written to database. If I write the same query in the terminal it writes into database then...

Comment: If I understand correctly what IBM says here :- https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_declaretable.html, you declared a table.  This is not the same as using CREATE TABLE.  Declared tables are used for syntax checking only not for keeping persistent data.

Comment: the table was not created in sqc but from command line. The create query is just in the code under comments. Create is one time job

Answer (score 0):

Nothing better then a cup of coffee the next day.
Embedded-SQL program requires the line

```
EXEC SQL COMMIT;
```